# how can I represent c# chart axis values exponentially?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

How can I show an ASP.NET Chart axis values in exponential model instead of linear representation?   So instead of displaying 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc, I want to display 0, 1, 10, 10^2, 10^3.

Comment: What are you using to display the charts?  If it's a 3rd party API, then the API would need to support this functionality.

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party API to display the chart , I'm using visual studio 2010 chart component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control, the `Axis` members of the `ChartArea` have an `IsLogarithmic` property:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
```